# Show all comments innerHtml Asp.net

Tags: asp.net, innerhtml

I want write all comments from database but writed last comment..

My Code:

```
 public void ShowComments(int id)
    {
        using (con = new OracleConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connectionString"].ToString()))
        {
            using (cmd = new OracleCommand("select name,comments from comments where id=" + id + "", con))
            {
                con.Open();
                OracleDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                while (dr.Read())
                {

                    comments.InnerHtml = "<br/>" + dr["name"] + ":" + dr["comments"] + "<br/>";
                }

                con.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```

Write last comment , I want all comment write to < div >..

```
    comments.InnerHtml = "<br/>" + dr["name"] + ":" + dr["comments"] + "<br/>";
```

aspx:

```
<div id="comments" runat="server">

</div>
```

Comment: you need to append the string in place of assign every time like  comments.InnerHtml += "your html"

Comment: yes worked , thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
comments.InnerHtml = "<br/>" + dr["name"] + ":" + dr["comments"] + "<br/>";
```

That overwrites the string stored in `comments.InnerHtml` for each row, thus only the last one shows up. Instead of overwriting that string, you need to append to it using the `+=` operator.

```
comments.InnerHtml += "<br/>" + dr["name"] + ":" + dr["comments"] + "<br/>";
```